# Run three different threads at a time

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am trying to run 3 threads at a time but every time I run this I get all 6 threads running at the same time. How can I make sure this doesn't happen?

```
    Dim iRisks() As String = {"$70"}
    Dim allTicks() As String = {"1.0", "1.1"}
    Dim iTimes() As String = {"210", "220", "240"}

    For Each iRisk In iRisks
        For Each iTime In iTimes
            For Each eachTick In allTicks
                Dim iThread1 As New Threading.Thread(New Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf FindStats))
                iThread1.Start(eachTick & "|" & iTime & "|" & iRisk)
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Use `Task` and `WhenAll` instead of threads.

Comment: Plus, what in there makes you think it would only run three at a time?

Comment: would it be possible to get a Task WhenAll sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're spawning 6 threads at the same time: `1 * 2 * 3 = 6`. Rethink on your strategy of attacking this matter and bare in mind SLaks comment concerning `Task` and `WhenAll`.